How can I add a dimension to Torch tensor with values of first two dimensions repeated in the new dimension
I have a Tensor of shape [a,b]. How can I reshape it to [a,b,c] such that all the values along the new dimensions repeat values of the i,j entry of the original tensor of shape [a,b]?
ex: a = 2, b= 3
tensor([[1,2,3],  
       [4,5,6]]) 

Now to reshape with c = 4 to get shape [2,3,4]
result:
tensor([[[1,1,1,1],
         [2,2,2,2],
         [3,3,3,3]],

         [4,4,4,4],
         [5,5,5,5],
         [6,6,6,6]]])


I guess the most fastforward way to do this is using the einops module. It provides a lot of tensor manipulations by making the transformations clearly visible. Here:
from einops import repeat
X = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
Y = repeat(X, "a b -> a b c", c=4)

Output:
tensor([[[1,1,1,1],
         [2,2,2,2],
         [3,3,3,3]],

         [4,4,4,4],
         [5,5,5,5],
         [6,6,6,6]]])


Confirmed that this indeed exactly what I needed. I appreciate the help!!

You can use a chain of repeat_interleave and unfold on the input tensor:
tensor.repeat_interleave(c, dim=1).unfold(dimension=1, size=c, step=c)

Example:
In [137]: tensor = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

In [138]: c = 4

In [139]: tensor.repeat_interleave(c, dim=1).unfold(dimension=1, size=c, step=c)
Out[139]: 
tensor([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 3, 3]],

        [[4, 4, 4, 4],
         [5, 5, 5, 5],
         [6, 6, 6, 6]]])

In [140]: tensor.repeat_interleave(c, dim=1).unfold(dimension=1, size=c, step=c).shape
Out[140]: torch.Size([2, 3, 4])


Yet another PyTorch-only solution would be using expand():
import torch

c = 4
x = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) 
y = x[:, :, None].expand(-1, -1, c)
print(y)
# >>> tensor([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
#              [2, 2, 2, 2],
#              [3, 3, 3, 3]],
#
#             [[4, 4, 4, 4],
#              [5, 5, 5, 5],
#              [6, 6, 6, 6]]])

Note that (see documentation):

Expanding a tensor does not allocate new memory, but only creates a new view on the existing tensor

This means that, although the values are now repeated c times, you still will not need c times as much memory (or rather, c+1 times as much memory, as x still exists, as well): y will just be a view into x, i.e. y will be a "reinterpretation" of the memory of x. The latter could be …

good for you if y is used in a read-only fashion, as it potentially saves a lot of memory (depending on the the size and number of repetitions),
bad for you if you also want to change the values in y.

